# Will a cooler master hyper 212 evo fit in a x11 advanced x-station case?

Tags: cpu, case, heatsink

I have a x11 advanced x-station case with an amd fx-6300 processor inside. I'm currently using the stock heat sink which isn't that great. Will a cooler master hyper 212 evo fit in the case?

Edit: My motherboard is an ASUSTeK M5A78L/USB3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of the Hyper 212 Evo cooler are:

```
Length:  80 mm
Width:  120 mm
Height: 159 mm
```

The easiest way is to measure the distance. In your case (no pun intended) I would solely worry about the height. Measure the distance between the Motherboard and the side panel. If its more than 160 mm, it should fit.